# Toggle a v-if on a slot component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to use the `intersectionObserver` to prevent loading of components up until the point that they are scrolled into view like so:

**Usage example:**

```
<lazy-component>
    <newsletter slot-scope="{}"></newsletter>
</lazy-component
```

The lazy component is a single file component which holds this template:

**LazyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <span>
        <slot v-if="visible"></slot>
    </span>
</template>
```

The newsletter component would get rendered if I did not add a `slot-scope` on it because it gets rendered first and only then gets inserted into the slot with a `v-if` statement.

At this point the component has been loaded and the if this would be an `async` component its Javascript would have been loaded as well. This is what I am trying to prevent.

Although the `slot-scope` works this feels pretty hacky and not clear to other users.

Would it be possible to set a `v-if` to `false` on the component in my templates and have the `lazy-component` manually set the `v-if` to `true` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you can do it by passing `visible` as a data to the slot.

**LazyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <span>
        <slot :visible="visible"></slot>
    </span>
</template>
```

**Using LazyComponent**

```
<lazy-component>
    <newsletter slot-scope="{visible}" v-if="visible"></newsletter>
</lazy-component
```